# Quick Key Problem HTC G2

Tags: keyboard, htc-desire-z

I have a Google G2 and for some reason the keyboard has set itself to open apps with almost every letter I push. For instance when I push the letter `e` on my keyboard it opens the email app. How do I turn this off?

Answer (score 0):

The slideout keyboard comes with Quick keys which you can assign to quickly open an app or an item when pressed.

1. Open the slideout keyboard.
2. Press and hold Shortcut key #1 to assign the first Quick key . Press and hold Shortcut key #2 to assign the second Quick key .
3. Tap OK
4. Tap Apps or Shortcuts, and then tap the app or shortcut that you want to assign to the selected Quick key. If you are assigning a shortcut to an item on your phone, follow the screen instructions to proceed.
5. Press the Quick key you’ve assigned. The app or item opens.

source: http://www.htc.com/help/www/howto_iframe.aspx?id=18599&type=1&p_id=325

Answer (score 0):

I had this phone, and I had this problem. Your "Search" key is stuck down -- press it a few times to unstick it.

This model has a feature where you can press search+e to open email. (It is, in fact, fully configurable.) When the search button gets stuck, those shortcuts activate, leading to the behavior you describe.